# SQL: Joining three tables on two sets of (hierarchical) IDs

Tags: sql, postgresql

OK, I am quite bad at SQL . Here is my problem setup.

I have three tables that I care about.
Table A has one field: IDs. This is a small number of IDs that I care about.
Table B has several fields: IDs (this can repeat) and let's say 9 other fields.

I want to aggregate over the relevant IDs in Table B and have the other 9 fields in an ARRAY_AGG struct. Relevant means that it's limited to the ones inside Table A. Note that Table B is massive so I must aggregate in order to write a reasonable sized result table.

This can be done pretty easily with something like:

```
SELECT 
  a.id, 
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT( 
    b.sub_id,
    b.field1, 
    b.field2,
    b.field3)
   ) AS b_fields
FROM table_a AS a
JOIN table_b AS b
USING(id);
```

My question comes in as follows: note that one of the fields is also an ID. I want to join on that sub_id with another table that looks as follows:

Table C: sub_id, field0

So, what I want to end up for my final table is something like this:

```
a.id, 
ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT( 
  b.sub_id,
  b.field1, 
  b.field2,
  b.field3,
  c.field0) as sub_level_info
```

The problem is I have no idea how to do this (as mentioned I suck at SQL). I do not want to join Table B and Table C beforehand because it would be huge and that would be slow. But I don't know if I can add the contents of Table C to the output of the join on Table A and Table B.

Does anyone know how to do this in a way that would be fast?

(For reference, suppose there about 250K ids in Table A and on the order of billions of elements in Tables B & C.)

Comment: What's the database engine? Oracle, DB2, PostgreSQL?

Comment: It's closest to PostgreSQL.

Comment: SQL is Declarative.  `a JOIN b JOIN c` doesn't necessarily get executed in that order.  Database Management Systems use cost based optimisers to work out the best way to solve the problem you declare.  Just declare the logic you need, then look at how to performance tune it ***after*** looking at EXPLAIN, etc.

Comment: @MatBailie, wow I think that was really all I needed to see. So I don't need to try to engineer anything in particular? Just join all three and let the dbms figure it out? That is super useful to know (again I know next to nothing about SQL!) Appreciate it.

Comment: Nothing is ever that simple.  But `a JOIN b JOIN c` should give the same plan as `c JOIN b JOIN a` for example.  Once you've expressed the problem you can use EXPLAIN to see how it's been solved and then look at options to improve performance.  You might see one step is taking 50% of the time, and you might see that adding an index would help dramatically, or try numerous other options.  But step one is always to express the problem and empirically test how the RDBMS solves it.